# In C++/CLI, how do I select the method to override when multiple overloads exist?

Tags: c#, inheritance, c++-cli

In a C# project, I have some types as follows:

```
public struct Struct<T> { public T Field; }
public interface IInterface<T>
{
    T F(T x);
}
public abstract class Class<T> : IInterface<T>, IInterface<Struct<T>> {
    virtual public T F(T x) { return x; }
    virtual public T F(Struct<T> x) { return x.Field; }
    Struct<T> IInterface<Struct<T>>.F(Struct<T> x) { return default(Struct<T>); }
}
```

In a C++/CLI project, I want to inherit from `Class<T>` and override the virtual `F` method:

```
public ref class Derived sealed : public Class<int> {
public:
    virtual int F(Struct<int> x) override;
};
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work:

```
error C2553: 'int Derived::F(Struct<T>)': overriding virtual function return type
differs from 'Struct<T> IInterface<Struct<T>>::F(Struct<T>)'
with
    [
        T=int
    ]
```

So it looks like the compiler wants to override the explicit interface implementation rather than the virtual method.

I have tried several variations, but none of them work. Sometimes I just get

```
error C3671: 'Derived:F' : function does not override 'IInterface<T>::F'
```

How do I specify the correct method to override?

**UPDATE**

If I add an explicit interface implementation of `IInterface::F`, as Ken suggests below, then the error messages disappear.

It looks like this is a C++/CLI compiler bug: I shouldn't have to re-implement an interface.

Unfortunately, although it's a good start for a work-around, the problem isn't solved entirely:

If I call `Derived::F` as an `IInterface`, then `Derived`'s explicit implementation (`IInterface_F`) is called. This is fine as a work-around if I can pass the call on to the implementation from the base class.

So the next question I have then is: how can I call an explicit interface implementation from the base class if I have an overload with the same signature (except return type) and also define an explicit implementation of the same interface in the derived class?

In other words, if I have in C#:

```
public interface IInterface {
    int F(int x);
}
public class A : IInterface {
    virtual long F(int x) { return 1L; }
    int IInterface.F(int x) { return 3; }
}
```

and in C++/CLI:

```
public ref class B : A {
public:
    virtual long F(int x) override { return 2L; }        
    virtual int IInterface_F(int x) sealed = IInterface::F {
        return ??? // call A's version of IInterface::F(x), which returns three
    }
}
```

How do I call `A`'s version of `IInterface::F` from `IInterface_F`?

Comment: For the updated question, try to implement class `B` in c# and you'll find the problem.

Comment: @KenKin In C# I there is no need to re-implement the interface so there is no issue.

Comment: Have you tried `override = Class<int>::F` ?

Answer (score 1):

With the code you provided(although `Class<T>` looks strange to me):

```
public ref class Derived sealed : public Class<int> {
public:
    virtual int F(Struct<int> x) override;
};
```

The compiler complains:

> error C2553: 'int Derived::F(Struct)': overriding virtual function return type differs from 'Struct IInterface>::F(Struct)'
>
> ```
>     with
>     [
>         T=int
>     ]
> ```
>
> error C3766: 'Derived' must provide an implementation for the interface method 'Struct IInterface>::F(Struct)'
>
> ```
>     with
>     [
>         T=int
>     ]
> ```
>
> error C3612: 'Derived': a sealed class cannot have any pure virtual methods
>       The following methods must be defined:
>
> ```
>     'Struct IInterface>::F(Struct)' : is abstract
>     with
>     [
>         T=int
>     ]
> ```

So I think provide an implementation for the interface method as the compiler says just solves the problem:

```
public ref class Derived sealed : public Class<int> {
public:
    virtual Struct<int> IInterface_F(Struct<int> x) 
        sealed=IInterface<Struct<int>>::F {
        return Struct<int>(); // equivalent to default(Struct<int>) in c#
    }

    virtual int F(Struct<int> x) override {
        return 0; // equivalent to default(int) in c#
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to eliminate the error messages, but see my update in the question for remaining issues. Oh, and don't worry if my code looks strange: it's a minimally reduced version of a much larger whole. I wanted to preserve anything that might be relevant.